# MediaRouter RemotePlaybackClient MediaItemStatus.PLAYBACK_STATE_FINISHED

Tags: android, chromecast

I am trying to use the MediaRouter api to do remote playback on a chromecast device. So far, discovering the chromecast, playing a video, polling for position updates, has worked very well. However, I am having huge problems getting a callback for when a media item has finished playing.

I have tried three different approaches:

1. in the RemotePlaybackClient.ItemActionCallback passed to
   remoteClient.play , I do not get the callback.
2. in the RemotePlaybackClient.StatusCallback statusCallback , set with remoteClient.setStatusCallback
3. using a handler to poll for status with remoteClient.getStatus.

I am thinking that for 1, I only get a callback saying if it started playing/buffering successfully, and that for 3. it would not really work for getting playback finished. Nr 3 works very well for getting updates on the position of the stream though.

If anyone has been able to get callbacks when a mediaItem has finished playing, I would be very glad to know how you did it.

Comment: Do you take a look at the democastplayer sample app that is part of the Android SDK?

Comment: Yes, the MediaRouter sample app, it crashes the google play service. Probably because it is passing null as bundle to Play. Documentation says you can pass null, but Google play services crashes when you do that. I found passing an empty Bundle works well.

Comment: After fixing that crash, I never receive the onItemStatusChanged callback. Actually upon further testing. The playlist queue of the sample app does not seem to be working at all. Bad sample app!